# How to fix that when sparse arrays are getting to big, the elements aren't shown anymore?

Tags: windows, julia, sparse-matrix

When I want to print large sparse arrays in Julia, the elements of the sparse array aren't shown. The only things that are printed, are dots on the position in the array where the elements aren't equal zero.
E.g:

```
julia> sparse(I,16,16)
16×16 SparseMatrixCSC{Bool, Int64} with 16 stored entries:
⠑⢄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠑⢄⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠑⢄⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠑⢄
```

For small arrays it works fine.

```
julia> sparse([1 0 ; 0 1])
2×2 SparseMatrixCSC{Int64, Int64} with 2 stored entries:
 1  ⋅
 ⋅  1
```

This problem only occurs when I am on Windows. On Linux it gets printed out with the specific elements shown correctly even if the array gets big. Like this:

```
julia> sparse([1.0, 0.0, 1.0])
3-element SparseVector{Float64, Int64} with 2 stored entries:
  [1]  =  1.0
  [3]  =  1.0
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just materialize the sparse array when wanting to display it:

```
julia> Matrix(sparse(I,16,16))
16×16 Matrix{Bool}:
 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

But what you perhaps wanted is `Base.print_matrix`:

```
julia> Base.print_matrix(stdout, sparse(2I,18,18))
 2  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  2  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  ⋅  2  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  2  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  2  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  2  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  2  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  2  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  2  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  2  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  2  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  2  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  2  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  2  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  2  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  2  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  2  ⋅
 ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  2
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it works, but I am just wondering why it has such a strange behaviour and if there isn't a solution to this. Because first of all it saves all those unnecessary zeros and secondly I think it is more viewable if it is sparse. And the arrays I am working with can get very large :D

Comment: `Base.print_matrix` ? the cut-off point is 16x16 so you need it call it yourself

Comment: Yes indeed, thats the solution. Thank you!

Comment: Do you maybe also know how I can get the representation like I get it on Linux in my example above?

Comment: Your last example is a vector not matrix and it will print in the same way on Windows.